# Weights and Measures + 3 Significant Digits

Tags: excel, units-of-measurement

I am looking to create a spreadsheet that will function as a tool similar a conversion website.

I am trying to convert units of measure (inches, feet, yards, millimeters and meters). When I input 36 inches, I need it to display the following:

- 36 inches
- 3 feet
- 1 yard
- 914 mm (technically this would be 914.4)
- .914 m (technically this would be 0.9144).

I am trying to create a formula that will not on convert the numbers, but also break it down to show 3 significant digits (without rounding).

For converting inches to feet I've come up with this formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((CONVERT(A7,"in","ft"))/10^(INT(LOG10(CONVERT(A7,"in","ft")))+1),3)*10^(INT(LOG10(CONVERT(A7,"in","ft")))+1)
```

This works until I hit larger numbers for example 40 inches will display as 1010 mm and I need it to display as 1016 mm.

I have the conversion piece down, so I guess what I'm asking is how do I get it to display 3 significant digits unless the numbers is over 100, in that case everything to the right of the decimal can be dropped.

Comment: Not sure I understand. To convert 40 inches to millimetres, why not use: =10^3*CONVERT(40,"in","m")?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest working with full precision in the calculations and using *custom number formatting* to adjust the decimal places displayed while retaining the underlying value's precision for further calculation.

[image: linear conversion]

Select the cell and tap `Ctrl+1` then choose *Custom* from the list down the left and supply a formatting mask for the Type:.

The formula in B8 is `=CONVERT($B$2,$C$2,"m")*POWER(10,3)` (nod to @XOR LX)  and the *custom number formatting* Type: is `[>=100]0 \m\m;0.000 \m\m`.

The formula in B9 is `=CONVERT($B$2,$C$2,"m")`  and the *custom number formatting* Type: is `[>=100]0 \m;0.000 \m`.

The value in C2 comes from a Data ► Data Validation List ► Allow: List ► Source: =$E$2:$E$9.

I've done B8 & B9. The rest should be pretty straightforward. Post back a comment if you need help with the formatting masks or other issues. see [Create a Custom Number Format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1 for the cool number format.  But I don't know that this addresses the significant figures criteria.  `=CONVERT(1.432,"in","mm")` returns "36.373 mm" using that format, which has 5 significant figures.

Comment: @RickHitchcock - You're right of course. I wan't paying enough attention to the phrase *display 3 significant digits*. CNF is limited to two scope conditions and a fallback so the best that could be done would be `[>=100]0 \m\m;[>=10]0.0 \m\m;0.00# \m\m`. Conditional formatting could adjust for additional value ranges if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you going:

```
=IF(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm")>=100,
    ROUND(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm"),0),
    ROUND(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm"),2-INT(LOG10(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm"))))
 )
```

This can be collapsed to:

```
=ROUND(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm"),
  (CONVERT(A2,"in","mm")<100)*(2-INT(LOG10(CONVERT(A2,"in","mm"))))
 )
```

**Output**

[image]

The number 2 gives you 3 significant figures.  Change to 3 for 4 significant figures, etc.